# How does the Stack Overflow Search Input work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How does the stack overflow search input at the top works? It seems to expand random or when it's empty and backspace is hit.

1. What is the jQuery, html and css behind it?
2. Does it replace or expand over the links?
3. Is there an other additional functionality I've missed?

Comment: I guess it expands on any keypress event not specific to backspace, which is actually very good UI. It gives more space to search a question. Yes, they are using JQuery, which you can see by opening web inspector or firebug etc.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/131866/187423

Comment: You can inspect their code if you wish.

Comment: And the menu is `hidden` when the search box expands, you can check that by inspecting the elements.

Comment: I was working on it. I was worried it was doing something that I would miss if I just inspected the input and the hlinks but perhaps I will delete.

Comment: worried about inspecting it????

Comment: @charlietfl. You need to know how you can do it, as jQuery handlers are not written inline.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How you can retrive the jQuery code of the search textbox?

This is the `<input>`:

```
<input autocomplete="off" name="q" class="textbox" placeholder="search" tabindex="1" type="text" maxlength="140" size="28" value="">
```

With little jQuery code (and knowing what you're doing), you can pull the event handlers:

```
$('.textbox[name="q"]').data('events')//Here jQuery saves internally the handlers
```

In that object you can see they have two handlers, one for `keydown` and one for `focusout`.

It's minified, but you can understand it if you wish:

**keydown**:

```
function (c){if(k||46>c.keyCode&&8!=c.keyCode&&32!=c.keyCode)return!0;k=!0;clearTimeout(e);d.clearQueue("expand");h(function(c){d[0].placeholder="";a.fadeOut(100,c)});h(function(c){d.animate({width:f,"max-width":f},100,c)});h(function(){0==d.parent().find(".search-prompt").length&&d.before('<span class="search-prompt">search:</span>')});3==d.queue("expand").length&&d.dequeue("expand")}
```

**focusout:**

```
function (){e=setTimeout(function(){h(function(c){d.parent().find(".search-prompt").remove(); c()});h(function(a){d.animate({width:c,"max-width":c},100,a)});h(function(c){n&&""==d[0].value&&(d[0].value="search");d[0].placeholder="search";a.fadeIn(100,c)});3==d.queue("expand").length&&d.dequeue("expand");k=!1},200)}
```

---

### Indented version:

**keydown**:

```
function(c) {
    if (k || 46 > c.keyCode && 8 != c.keyCode && 32 != c.keyCode) return !0;
    k = !0;
    clearTimeout(e);
    d.clearQueue("expand");
    h(function(c) {
        d[0].placeholder = "";
        a.fadeOut(100, c)
    });
    h(function(c) {
        d.animate({
            width: f,
            "max-width": f
        }, 100, c)
    });
    h(function() {
        0 == d.parent().find(".search-prompt").length && d.before('<span class="search-prompt">search:</span>')
    });
    3 == d.queue("expand").length && d.dequeue("expand")
}​
```

**focusout:**

```
function() {
    e = setTimeout(function() {
        h(function(c) {
            d.parent().find(".search-prompt").remove();
            c()
        });
        h(function(a) {
            d.animate({
                width: c,
                "max-width": c
            }, 100, a)
        });
        h(function(c) {
            n && "" == d[0].value && (d[0].value = "search");
            d[0].placeholder = "search";
            a.fadeIn(100, c)
        });
        3 == d.queue("expand").length && d.dequeue("expand");
        k = !1
    }, 200)
}​
```

This answer shows you you can achieve anything you want in the WEB development.
                **NOTHING IS SECRET!**

Comment: This is pretty close. There is a few thing missing but I'll edit in when I'm done unminifying

Comment: @jpiasetz. That can take you a while... `:)`

Comment: @jpiasetz. Hi, I looked at your suggested edit, but it has nothing to do with your question. what you saw is feature of SE letting you type a search expression clicking ctrl + enter to open the result in a new page.

Comment: How does that not have to do with the search input? I think it would fall under #3 since I was just general asking what everything the box in the top did.

Comment: @jpiasetz. [Read this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137117/a-hidden-undocumented-se-keyboard-shortcut-for-searching)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to achieve this using jQuery, the basics are:

```
$('.search-input').keydown(function() {
    $(this).animate({width: '200px'}, {duration: 200});
});

$('.search-input').blur(function(){
    $(this).animate({width: '100px'}, {duration: 200});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery, html and css behind it. It replace or expand over the links.

```
$('.search-input').keydown(function() {
$(this).css( "height","100");
$("hlinks").show();
  });

$('.search-input').blur(function(){
$(this).css( "height","200");
 $("hlinks").hide();
});
```

Comment: It's a lot more than just that. `:)`